# Accessing VM Guest from my mobile devices in same network

Tags: networking, vmware, virtualization

I made a VM with Bridged connection and I can ping my guest from host.
Now, I need my device can ping my VM guest. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Some networks have issues with bridged VMs but a normal home network shouldn't

When using bridged networks you effectively create a virtual switch where both your computer and VM connect to.
This means that a virtual machine will behave like any other machine in the network.
You need to go into virtual network settings and if possible set bridged settings to just one network interface or atleast remove things like bluetooth network.
Check that your virtual machine is actually getting an IP address from your router and then you should be able to get to the machine from anywhere in the same network.